# How to run a code block each Monday of the week and start of the month in Kotlin/Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on my final year project where  I have requirements to set/re-set some values on Firestore these would be Firebase Firestore APIs calls. and I need these two blocks of codes to be run one block each Monday at 12am and another each 1st day of the month at 12 am.

I will really appreciate the seniors' help in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: AlarmManager, WorkManager (no exact timings though).

Comment: Can’t understand your point can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, you are looking for the [WorkManager API](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager). [This](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) is a detailed walk-through and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) is the actual reference documentation.

If you need to run your code at *precisely* 12am **and** the user expects to be notified about it, then you should use the [AlarmManager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager). However, as mentioned throughout the documentation, alarms greatly interrupt the device's attempts to minimize battery usage.